# Moving /var/mail to different partition, drive or pc

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, dovecot

My managed server (Ubuntu 16.04, Postfix, Dovecot) had random accedent and in the end mail server was not working. Postfix had random randomness and it couldnt access mysql and Im using virtual users whit postfix and dovecot. Reapplying permission to db user it was quite working, mail was incoming but users cannot login. I fixed that by changing passwords, disabling appguard and maybe something else, I was in panic. Now it works, I hope so still and question is I have an idea to move /var/mail to different partition, drive or pc, create full os partition volume image backup and in case like this just use yesterdays backup image and mail server should from place where it stopped working. Is it possible or is a good idea is first place?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very hard to read. If you're interested in backing up your mail and configuration, you can simply copy the contents of the configurations from `/etc`. If you want to backup the mail-store, you can copy `/var/mail`. You can copy these anywhere you want.

For simplicity, I would suggest creating a tar bundle with a command such as the following:

`tar czf /path/to/safe/backup/location/<backup-name>.tgz /etc /var/mail`

This will create a compressed tar file which contains all of the configurations in `/etc` (including Postfix and Dovecot) and also all of the email from `/var/mail`